# Whatsmeow conversation data

Tags: go, whatsapp

I'm trying to build a [tui client for WhatsApp](https://github.com/WinterSunset95/WhatsGo) using [whatsmeow](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mau.fi/whatsmeow).

After half a day of searching and reading through the docs, I still can't find a way to get the conversation data of individual contacts. Any help is appreciated.

I found [ParseWebMessage](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mau.fi/whatsmeow#Client.ParseWebMessage) but I'm not really sure how to use this.

```
chatJID, err := types.ParseJID(conv.GetId())
for _, historyMsg := range conv.GetMessages() {
    evt, err := cli.ParseWebMessage(chatJID, historyMsg.GetMessage())
    yourNormalEventHandler(evt)
}
```

Matter of fact I'm not even sure if this is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you basically linked to the part of the docs that contains the information you're looking for. The return type of the `ParseWebMessage` call is `events.Message`, documented [here](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mau.fi/whatsmeow@v0.0.0-20221126173344-e660988acdbc/types/events#Message). It contains an `Info` field of type `MessageInfo` (again, [documented here](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mau.fi/whatsmeow@v0.0.0-20221126173344-e660988acdbc/types#MessageInfo)). In turn, this `MessageInfo` type embeds the `MessageSource` type [see docs here](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mau.fi/whatsmeow@v0.0.0-20221126173344-e660988acdbc/types#MessageSource) which looks like this:

```
type MessageSource struct {
    Chat     JID  // The chat where the message was sent.
    Sender   JID  // The user who sent the message.
    IsFromMe bool // Whether the message was sent by the current user instead of someone else.
    IsGroup  bool // Whether the chat is a group chat or broadcast list.

    // When sending a read receipt to a broadcast list message, the Chat is the broadcast list
    // and Sender is you, so this field contains the recipient of the read receipt.
    BroadcastListOwner JID
}
```

So to get the contact who sent a given message, given your code `evt, err := cli.ParseWebMessage()`, you need to check:

```
evt, err := cli.ParseWebMessage(chatJID, historyMsg.GetMessage())
if err != nil {
    // handle error, of course
}
fmt.Printf("Sender ID: %s\nSent in Chat: %s\n", evt.Info.Sender, evt.Info.Chat)
if evt.Info.IsGroup {
    fmt.Printf("%s is a group chat\n", evt.Info.Chat)
}
```

You can also skip messages you sent by simply doing this:

```
if evt.Info.IsFromMe {
    continue
}
```

The `evt.Info.Chat` and `evt.Info.Sender` fields are all of type `JID`, [documented here](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mau.fi/whatsmeow@v0.0.0-20221126173344-e660988acdbc/types#JID). There essentially are 2 variations of this ID type: user and server JID's and AD-JIDs (user, agent, and device). You can distinguish between the two by checking the `JID.AD` flag.

I haven't used this module at all, I only scanned through the docs briefly, but as I understand it, this module allows you to write a handler which will receive an `events.Message` type for everything you receive. By checking the `evt.Info.IsGroup`, you can work out whether the message we sent in a group chat, or in your person-to-person conversation thing. Based on `evt.Info.Sender` and `evt.Info.Chat`, you can work out who sent the message. The `evt.Info.Sender` being  a JID in turn allows you to call [the `GetUserInfo` method](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mau.fi/whatsmeow@v0.0.0-20221126173344-e660988acdbc#Client.GetUserInfo), passing in the JID, which gets you a `UserInfo` object in return [as documented here](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mau.fi/whatsmeow@v0.0.0-20221126173344-e660988acdbc/types#UserInfo), showing the name, picture, status, etc...

So I guess you're looking for something along these lines:

```
// some map of all messages from a given person, sent directly to you
contacts := cli.GetAllContacts() // returns map[JID]ContactInfo
personMsg := map[string][]*events.Message
evt, err := cli.ParseWebMessage(chatJID, historyMsg.GetMessage())
if err != nil {
    // handle
}
if !evt.Info.IsFromMe && !evt.Info.IsGroup {// not a group, not sent by me
    info, _ := cli.GetUserInfo([]types.JID{evt.Info.Sender})
    if contact, ok := contacts[info[evt.Info.Sender]; ok {
        msgs, ok := personMsg[contact.PushName]
        if !ok {
            msgs := []*events.Message{}
        }
        personMsg[contact.PushName] = append(msgs, evt)
    }
}
```

Note the `ContatInfo` type didn't show up in the docs right away, but I stumbled across it [in the repo](https://github.com/tulir/whatsmeow/blob/e660988acdbc420421d5a3d58ea9f3faba49b2ed/types/user.go#L39).

Either way, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, and how/why you're stuck. All it took to find this information was to check the return type of the `ParseWebMessage` method you mentioned, check a couple of types, and scroll through some of the listed/documented methods to get a rough idea of how you can get all the data you could possibly need...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I reeeeally needed this